# Group by on the columns of a data frame and on the values ​of a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, `df`, like:

```
Year    Month      Country    Organizer      Participation
2020      1         China     FAO                True
2020      1         Japan     FAO                True
2020      1         France    EU                 False
2020      2         France    FAO                False
2020      2         Japan     FAO                True
2020      2         Germany   EU                 True
2020      2         Finland   EU                 False
2020      2         India     FAO                True
2020      3         Senegal   FAO                True
```

and a dictionary, `codes`:

```
codes = {
    'Asia': ['China', 'Japan', 'India'],
    'Europe': ['France', 'Germany', 'Finland'],
    'Africa': ['Senegal']
}
```

My goal is to perform a group by considering the fields `'Year'`, `'Month'`, `'Organizer'` and the continent (in the `df` I have `'Country'`), counting the number of rows. `'Participation'` is not important.

To be more precise my final output should be:

```
Year    Month      Organizer    Continent    Number
2020      1         FAO          Asia          2
2020      1         EU           Europe        1
2020      2         FAO          Europe        1
2020      2         FAO          Asia          2
2020      2         EU           Europe        2
2020      3         FAO          Africa        1
```

Is there a compact way to do this? The alternative way would be to add a column `'Continent'` and also use this column in the group by, but I'm afraid this is inefficient and inelegant solution.

Comment: You must add a new column for continent, because you must create a pandas groupby object and for it you must have list of grouper columns. I think adding this columns is very easy and fast. Can you describe more about your problem

Comment: Are you sure about the expected output ? The dictionary named codes doesn't have India but expected output seems to be included in the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a map using the dictionary to create a column 'Continent' and then do `value_counts`.

```
out = df.assign(
    Continent=df.Country.map({v: key for key, values in codes.items() for v in values})
).drop(
    ["Country", "Participation"], axis=1
).value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().rename(
    {0: "Number"}, axis="columns"
)

print(out)

   Year  Month Organizer Continent  Number
0  2020      1       FAO      Asia       2
1  2020      2        EU    Europe       2
2  2020      1        EU    Europe       1
3  2020      2       FAO      Asia       1
4  2020      2       FAO    Europe       1
5  2020      3       FAO    Africa       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new_codes={i:k for k,v in codes.items() for i in v} #{'China': 'Asia', 'Japan': 'Asia', 'India': 'Asia', 'France': 'Europe', 'Germany': 'Europe', 'Finland': 'Europe', 'Senegal': 'Africa'}
df['Continent'] = df['Country'].replace(new_codes)
dfx = df.groupby(['Year','Month','Organizer','Continent']).agg(number=('Continent',"count"))
```

**Output**:

```
   Year  Month Organizer Continent  number
0  2020      1        EU    Europe       1
1  2020      1       FAO      Asia       2
2  2020      2        EU    Europe       2
3  2020      2       FAO      Asia       2
4  2020      2       FAO    Europe       1
5  2020      3       FAO    Africa       1
```

If you don't want to create a new column, you can use:

```
new_codes={i:k for k,v in codes.items() for i in v} #{'China': 'Asia', 'Japan': 'Asia', 'India': 'Asia', 'France': 'Europe', 'Germany': 'Europe', 'Finland': 'Europe', 'Senegal': 'Africa'}
dfx = df.groupby(['Year','Month','Organizer',df['Country'].replace(new_codes)]).agg(number=('Country',"count")).reset_index().rename(columns={'Country':'Continent'})
```